# How to properly return character values for dplyr's do?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider the following code:

```
foo <- function() {
  if (runif(1) < 0.5) {
    return(data.frame(result="low"))
  } else {
    return(data.frame(result="high"))
  }
}

df = data.frame(val=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
df %>% group_by(val) %>% do(foo())
```

It is random, but if there are both "low" and "high" results returned, you'll see errors like this:

```
Warning messages:
1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
4: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
5: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
  binding character and factor vector, coercing into character vector
```

I believe the first value being returned (say, "low") is converted into a factor with one level, and when the other level comes along, it incurs dplyr's wrath.

What is the proper way to code this example to avoid the warnings?

**Edit**: One solution is this:

```
foo <- function() {
  if (runif(1) < 0.5) {
    return(data.frame(result=factor("low", levels=c("low", "high"))))
  } else {
    return(data.frame(result=factor("high", levels=c("low", "high"))))
  }
}
```

But what if I don't know the factor levels ahead of time?

Also, more fundamentally, I'd like to return a character vector, not a factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either:

- Use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`: `return(data.frame(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE))`

Or:

- Use `data_frame`: `return(data_frame(...))`

See ?data.frame for more about factor treatment.

Comment: You're a crazy R genius. I've forgotten stringsAsFactors 100 times.